addValueEventListener resets variables outside of it
I want to get the user variable outside of the ValueEventListener. But addValueEventListener removes the value of the variables. It writes Null there and that's it.
private void setInitialData(){
        TextView label=findViewById(R.id.label);
        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(USER_KEY);
        String t=getIntent().getStringExtra("EmailUser");

        rootRef.orderByChild("Email").equalTo(t).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user=ds.getValue(User.class);
                    listdata.add(user);
                }
                rootRef.removeEventListener(this);
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });



how do I get the user variable outside of the ValueEventListener?????
I tried to get it through hidden text - it didn't help. tried through the final variable. nothing helped

Data is loaded from Firebase (and most cloud APIs) asynchronously, as it takes some time to load. While the data is being loaded, your main code continues to work and that's typically the code outside of your onDataChange. That's why any code that needs the data from Firebase has to be inside onDataChange, be called from there, or be otherwise synchronized.

and how do I then get the value of the variable?

My answer to the first question I linked shows how to do this with a custom callback.
